# Launch msoffice document viewer from custom iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, powerpoint, viewer

I am designing an app that shall download MS Office documents (PowerPoint, Word) from a server and launch a viewer like Documents to Go.

Is it possible to download a PowerPoint from a server in HTTP, save it on the iPad drive and pass the URL of the document to a PowerPoint viewer while launching it from my custom app?
I know I can launch an app through a custom URL scheme, but do you know of a viewer that can be called by an URL scheme with the location of the file to display passed in parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can **download** the .ppt , word file and save that in your **application bundle**.
and you could open the Docs with `UIWebView` .

[Using UIWebView to display select document types](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1630/_index.html)

Comment: Thanks Jhaliya for the reply i know about this solution but i dont want to use a uiwebview as the render is not really good
i want to use an external viewer application for better rendering.
Anyone knows about a viewer that i can call through its custom url scheme from my native app passing in parameter the url of the document to display? Cheers, Benoit

Answer (score 0):

Rather than launching the app directly through a url, providing users the option to open your documents in another app would be the compatible/future-proof way to go. For that, you can use a UIDocumentInteractionController. More details on that can be found in this SO question:

[Adding "Open In..." option to iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981199/adding-open-in-option-to-ios-app)