# iOS show up in list of 'sharing apps'

Tags: ios, api, data-sharing

I dont know what this is called and cant find anything on this...

When your in iphoto and click share a list of apps show up to do the sharing through, facebook and Twitter (if installed) email, sms, etc.  How do I get my app in that list so when the user wants to share a photo my application is available to be the one to do the sharing. Im assuming the ios passes the photo to the app and myapp catches it and does work with it.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981199/adding-open-in-option-to-ios-app

Comment: You can't. Apple doesn't show 3rd party apps in the Photos app. File an enhancement request with Apple. There's no reason why Apple should have this restriction.

Comment: @rmaddy so the only reason facebook and twitter are in there is because they filed a request and were approved (and are giant popular sites)? Also is this resteicted just for photos or for anything else that has a share button?

Comment: I have no idea why Apple made the Photos app such that 3rd party apps don't appear on the share sheet even if other apps can handle images. You need to ask them. I do know that if another 3rd party apps choose to share an image, other 3rd party apps that claim to handle images will appear in the "Open In..." menu.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible for 3rd party applications.