# Open Files from other apps in own app

Tags: ios, swift, file

my english is not the best and i even don't know how to search for it so i have to describe my question.
I am programming (in Swift 2) an app playing music. Everything is working. Shared iTunes folder, choosing a file and open it. But how can i open/import a file from an other app?
lets say i've downloaded a mp3 file in Safari and want to open it in my own app by clicking this little "open in" button.
How can i add my app to this "open in dialogue"?
(I want to import it to my shared iTunes folder)
A link to a tutorial or sth. would be nice.

Comment: Please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981199/adding-open-in-option-to-ios-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To declare its support for file types, your app must include the CFBundleDocumentTypes key in its Info.plistproperty list file.

> The CFBundleDocumentTypes key contains an array of dictionaries, each
>   of which identifies information about a specific document type. A
>   document type usually has a one-to-one correspondence with a
>   particular file type. However, if your app treats more than one file
>   type the same way, you can group those file types together to be
>   treated by your app as a single document type. For example, if you
>   have an old and new file format for your application’s native document
>   type, you could group both together in a single document type entry.
>   This way, old and new files would appear to be the same document type
>   and would be treated the same way.

```
<dict>
   <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
   <string>My File Format</string>
   <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
       <array>
           <string>MySmallIcon.png</string>
           <string>MyLargeIcon.png</string>
       </array>
   <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
       <array>
           <string>com.example.myformat</string>
       </array>
   <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
   <string>Owner</string>
</dict>
```

This page from the Apple doc should help you,
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1